# These characters were added to random files. I'am not able to understand the cause for the error

Tags: android, xml

/*
 * Copyright (C) 2018 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org

G:\bunch\views-widgets-samples-master\listview\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml:1: AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Comment: Sometimes extra files get generated by Android Studio. A simple solution for this is:
Go to Build> Clean project.
then Build>Rebuild Project.
After that go to File>Invalidate Caches and Restart. 
This will clean your project and will clear all unnecessary files.

Comment: I followed this : Go to Build> Clean project. then Build>Rebuild Project. After that go to File>Invalidate Caches and Restart. It says"Gradle project sync failed.Basic functionality will not work properly."

Comment: Please post your XML code where you have faced that problem.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <item name="android.net.nsd.NsdManager">
    <annotation name="android.support.annotation.SystemService">
      <val name="value" val="android.content.Context.NSD_SERVICE"/>
    </annotation>
  </item>
</root>

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
     build file 'G:\Whatsapp\build.gradle': 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>